# refresh array without page load

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, refresh

I implemented a functionality in angular, Where i'm showing the filtered array details in grid.
on clicking a button in grid, i'm calling a function onClick() whre we can update the record.
When the record is updated, i need to refresh the filtered array, without reloading the page.
Help me achieve this functionality.

```
 selected:any;
  filtered : any=[];
  Form: FormGroup;

    onOptionsSelected() {
      if (this.Form.invalid) {
        alert('Please choose an option')
        return;        
      }
      else{
      this.filtered = this.studentInfo.filter(t=>t.Id == this.selected);
      }      
    }  

    public Response: any = [];

    onClick(index: number, id: string, roll_no: string){
      const obj = {
        id : id,
        roll_no : roll_no,
      }      
     this.Srvc.postmethod('students', obj).subscribe((response:any)=>{
        this.Response = response;
        if(this.Response.status === 200)
        {
          alert('Record updated');                  
        }  
   });
  }
```

Comment: Update array in service response. It will automatic reflect in grid as Arrays are compared with reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response. like how? can you please elaborate with the code.

Comment: Where is your onAcceptClick function ? could you please add this in question ?  then i would get some idea about array manipulation

Comment: Sorry, it's onClick function. Edited question

Comment: okay now tell me ansewers of few questions..., What do you mean by record updated ? Are you looping in HTML over that array ? 

I assume record updated means manipulation of array.

Comment: In html using ngfor i show the filtered array data.
using the index, id and roll_no of a particular record in grid..i update a record by onClick.
Everything is working fine.
I only need to refresh the grid/ the filtered array only. after successful update alert. without reloadingwhole page.

Comment: I'm actually using a dropdown. Initially, page will be empty.  on selected item from dropdown, the filtered array will display. so when i use window.locaation.reload() in onclick(). whole page is getting reloaded and page is going to be empty again. I need to fix this.

Comment: Edited the question, added code. After onclick, if status is 200, the dropdown should again be back to selected value and the grid should refresh.

Comment: in HTML .. on which variable you are looping ? are you looping `this.Response` ?

Comment: looping the filtered array only. Updated question sir,

Comment: okay so when you update the records you need to filter the array again `this.filtered = this.studentInfo.filter(t=>t.Id == this.selected);` inside the subscription in onClick method

Comment: okay filtering is working. But, it's not refreshing with updated values. OnClick the grid remains the same. I need to refresh grid with updated values.

Comment: what exactly you are updating in the grid ?

Comment: Hi sir please help me with this...... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66059433/form-array-validation-add-new-text-box-only-after-validation-of-the-present-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

Update the filtered array with the status as Y at desired index so that it will reflect in grid.

```
 onClick(index: number, id: string, roll_no: string){
          const obj = {
            id : id,
            roll_no : roll_no,
          }      
         this.Srvc.postmethod('students', obj).subscribe((response:any)=>{
            this.Response = response;
            if(this.Response.status === 200)
            {
              alert('Record updated');  
              this.filtered[index].present = 'Y'  // try this line
            }  
       });
      }
```